# Reading boolean values from Sqlite database in Windows Phone

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am reading data from a database table having columns with type bool. I am using the Sqlite library for Windows Phone 8.

Here is the code i am using

```
quotes = new ObservableCollection<Quotes>(
            await connection.QueryAsync<Quotes>("Select * from Quotes where quote_type ='" + category + "'"));
```

Here is my Quotes class

```
public class Quotes
{
    public int _id { get; set; }
    public string quote { get; set; }
    public string quote_type { get; set; }
    public string author { get; set; }
    public bool IsFav { get; set; }
    public bool IsUserDefined { get; set; }
}
```

I am getting all the values but the "IsFav" and "IsUserDefined" variable always contain the value "False" even though there are some data in the table for which the value is true. The variable and column name in the table also match.

Comment: Are you sure that the `IsFaV` and `IsUserDefined` are spelt exactly the same in the DB? Are you sure that both of these fields are of type bool in the server too?

Comment: According to: http://sqlite.org/datatype3.html - sql lite doesn't store bools. Instead, it stores them as 1 (true) and 0 (false).

Comment: @Subby yes the names are spelt correctly in both the places

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get it working.

Changed the data stored in Sqlite db boolean column to 0 and 1 instead of true and false.